# Как правильно составить выражение XPath, чтобы исключить тег?

Tags: php, xpath, выражение

Вот HTML фрагмент:

```html
<div class="content">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>Состав:</p>
    <br>
Вода, сахар, краситель
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Необходимо составить выражение XPath в ->query(), чтобы на выходе ->nodeValue получился текст "Состав:Вода, сахар, краситель". То есть нужно взять все содержимое блока `<div class="content">`, но исключить содержимое первого `<h3>`. Есть какие-либо идеи?

Answer (score 0):

берём родительский DOMNodeList (точнее набор)

```
$productDescriptionObj = $productFinder->query("//div[@class='content']");
```

берём DOMNodeList (точнее набор), в котором node, который нужно исключить

```
$productDescriptionTitleObj = $productFinder->query("./h3", $productDescriptionObj[0]);
```

берём непосредственно node

```
$productDescriptionTitle = $productDescriptionTitleObj->item(0);
```

вырезаем node из ветки (нужно обращаться через родителя)

```
$productDescriptionTitle->parentNode->removeChild($productDescriptionTitle);
```

берём весь контент родителя, где уже нету h3, контент которого нужно было исключить

```
$productDescription = $productDescriptionObj[0]->nodeValue;
```